# Textmate simple find/replace with regex

Tags: regex, textmate

I would like to obtain this result:

```
  .col-xs-1       
      i.fa.fa-angellist
  .col-xs-1
      i.fa.fa-area-chart
  .col-xs-1
      i.fa.fa-at
```

from this code:

```
  .col-xs-1    

      i.fa.fa-angellist
      | fa-angellist
  .col-xs-1

      i.fa.fa-area-chart
      | fa-area-chart
  .col-xs-1

      i.fa.fa-at
      | fa-at
```

I've tried to find `| fa-(.*)` and replace it with a `whitespace` without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't have TextMate to verify.

Please try to search for `^(  \.col-xs-1 *\r)\r(      i\.fa\.fa-[-a-z]+\r)      \| fa-[-a-z]+\r` and to replace with `\1\2`.

There is a different number of blanks in source's and result's respective first line. (I noticed as I did actually copy from your question.) If intentional, this will require the search expression's adjustment. Regarding your own search expression: The pipe character is being used to denote alternatives, and needs to be escaped if actually part of the to be matched string.

Comment: I would like to find all  `| fa-x` where x=angelist for instance

Comment: Is `\| fa-[-a-z]+` getting anywhere close?

Comment: Could you clarify a little for me? I feel like, looking at the code posted up top, that scanning for the `| fa-x` is not the best approach. Which makes me think that I am not understanding what it is you want to accomplish..  However if you for sure just want to match `| fa-x` then I think this will suffice:  `\|\sfa-\S+`

Comment: @BenjaminBenoudis Just out of curiosity: My original suggestion should have matched a block of four lines - in order to bring about the required changes. And the [TextMate docu](http://manual.macromates.com/en/regular_expressions#syntax_oniguruma) seems to support it. Did you possibly remove the blank lines earlier?

Comment: @Abecee Yes finally I've used your solution to remove all the `| fa-x`then I've used a tool to tabify and remove all blank spaces and lines.

Comment: @BenjaminBenoudis Is there anything left to be addressed? ;-)